# Highcharts X axis date bold

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, highcharts

I am trying to make the date bold and red color in my highcharts x axis where time is also present in 12 hour format. I have done the following code but it is making all of the elements in x axis as bold as my time is in 12 hour format.

```
Highcharts.each($('.highcharts-xaxis-labels')[0].children, function(p, i) {
                    if (p.textContent.match(/[a-z]/i)) {
                      $(p).css({
                        fill: '#951515',
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                      })
                    }
                  })
```

How do I achieve this ?

[image: Output]

Comment: So you want only the date (May 31) to be bold black... And no change for the rest?

Comment: Yes @LouysPatriceBessette and it is bold red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this change in the condition to match.

If it is NOT a time, make it bold black.

```
Highcharts.each($('.highcharts-xaxis-labels')[0].children, function(p, i) {
  if ( !p.textContent.match(/\d\d[ap]m/i)) {
    $(p).css({
      fill: '#951515',
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    })
  }
})
```

`\d\d[ap]m` will match `04am`, `16pm`, etc.